# MySQL searching JSON array for value, using `like` or regexp

Tags: mysql, sql, json, json-extract

I have a table with a field called `data_json`.

An example of the JSON shape is below:

```
{
  title: "My Title",
  arr: ["hello there", "foobar", "foo hello bar"]
}
```

I'd simply like to find rows where `data_json->'$.arr'` contains a value, using `regexp`, or `like`.

Eg:

```
select * from mytable where ??? like '%hello%';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to extract the elements of the array. To perform this `JSON_EXTRACT()` function might be used along with index values upto the length of it. Row generation methods through metadata tables of `information_schema`, such like below, might be used to generate those index values :

```
SELECT value
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT  @i := @i + 1 AS rn,
           JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data_json, CONCAT('$.arr[',@i-1,']'))) AS value              
      FROM information_schema.tables 
     CROSS JOIN mytable 
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) r
  ) q
 WHERE value LIKE '%hello%'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=33e63c0a893ca146cafd828389fa4504)</kbd>